# How to fix sudo docker compose - compose is not a docker command

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, installation

[sudo command not working, but normal docker is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoLXY.png)

I followed the steps from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/#install-the-plugin-manually)

The above steps have been followed cut to cut, but was not able to find the docker compose command in root. In the `non-sudo` I am only able to run the version command but nothing more because of access permissions are not available, any solutions to this?

And no, using `sudo su` and then using `docker compose` also doesn't work